# ORACLE APEX ADMIN LOGIN ISSUE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am getting an authentication required message on google chrome when logging into oracle apex admin.

screenshot of error:
[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: can you give us more information? apex does require authentication

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. It is normal that Apex asks for credentials, whenever you login as a developer or as an admin. So - did you provide what you've been asked? Could you explain it a little bit more, perhaps even attach a screenshot?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.I have added a screenshot of the error .

Comment: Well, that doesn't look like Apex login screen. I expected something like this (on apex.oracle.com): https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550:1 . I have no idea what your *photography* represents. Do you, by any chance, use Apache Tomcat? Maybe both Oracle and Tomcat use the same port. If so, change one of them.

Comment: as @Littlefoot said that's not apex, that's the XDB Listener so you may have a port conflict. 2 options are here to change the ports https://stackoverflow.com/a/48717209/3715100

Comment: I'm facing the same problem after installing apex 18.2. When using chrome it only prompts for a user/password. But when using IE it gives a bit more information: "server informs that is from XDB" (this might be a bad translation,sorry).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the embedded PL/SQL Gateway and the XDB Protocol Server, correct?  If so, please ensure:

- You have run @apex_epg_config.sql
- You have unlocked the ANONYMOUS database user

https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/HTMIG/configuring-embedded-PL-SQL-gateway.htm#HTMIG29205

Answer (score 4):

Why this happens?  Because the ANONYMOUS account is locked and/or expired.

Log in to main container database (not PDB)

Run the following query to determine status:

```
select account_status from dba_users where username = 'ANONYMOUS';
```

If `account_status` is expired, run the following:

```
alter user ANONYMOUS identified by anonymous;

alter user ANONYMOUS account unlock;
```

If `account_status` is locked, run the following:

```
alter user ANONYMOUS account unlock;
```

Answer (score 1):

When using IE instead of Chrome the login message refers to `XDB`. It seems like a problem with anonymous connection. This [thread](https://community.oracle.com/thread/643846?start=0&tstart=0) gives a solution for enabling this anonymous access. Though I think this is not probably a good solution, I don't have enough knowledge to solve it in a better way. In case the link is broken, I'm pasting the solution here. It worked for me, and I've seen this solution in a few more places so I maybe this is quite common...
(with  `CONN sys/password AS SYSDBA`)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
    l_configxml XMLTYPE;
    l_value VARCHAR2(5) := 'true'; -- (true/false)
BEGIN
    l_configxml := DBMS_XDB.cfg_get();

    IF l_configxml.existsNode('/xdbconfig/sysconfig/protocolconfig/httpconfig/allow-repository-anonymous-access') = 0 THEN
    -- Add missing element.
        SELECT insertChildXML
        (
            l_configxml,
             '/xdbconfig/sysconfig/protocolconfig/httpconfig',
             'allow-repository-anonymous-access',
             XMLType('<allow-repository-anonymous-access xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdbconfig.xsd">' ||
             l_value ||
             '</allow-repository-anonymous-access>'),
             'xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdbconfig.xsd"'
         )
        INTO l_configxml
        FROM dual;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Element inserted.');
    ELSE
        -- Update existing element.
        SELECT updateXML
        (
            DBMS_XDB.cfg_get(),
            '/xdbconfig/sysconfig/protocolconfig/httpconfig/allow-repository-anonymous-access/text()',
            l_value,
            'xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/xdbconfig.xsd"'
        )
        INTO l_configxml
        FROM dual;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Element updated.');
    END IF;

    DBMS_XDB.cfg_update(l_configxml);
    DBMS_XDB.cfg_refresh;
END;
/
```

Comment: this solution if Error Message appears: The site Says: "XDB"